# spring @RequestParam Unicode not getting correctly

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am using Spring to create RESTful service in java.
I have controller defined below:

```
package com.pro.controller;    

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/favorites")
public class FavoritesController extends SkeletonController {

    protected static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("FavoritesController");

    @Autowired
    private FavoritesService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public StandardResult savePaymentList(
            @RequestParam(value = "sessionId", required = true) String sessionId,
            @RequestParam(value = "comment", required = true) String comment,
            @RequestParam(value = "serviceId", required = true) int serviceId,
            @RequestParam(value = "fields", required = true) String fields) throws Exception {

        log.info("sessionId:" + sessionId + ", serviceId:" + serviceId + ", fields:" + fields + ", comment:" + comment);

        SavePaymentListRequest request = new SavePaymentListRequest();
        request.setLang("en");
        request.setSid(sessionId);
        request.setSessionRequestType(SessionRequestType.MOBILE);


        request.setFields(arrOfFields);
        return service.savePaymentList(request);
    }  

}
```

Now i have call it from different clients to accurate if problem on client or service.
Last i have tried on: chrome-extension: POSTMAN.
i am executing this method with POST option and my request query string is:
https://xx_mydomain_xx.com/fake/favorites/save/sessionId=cd6c5d88-771e-4831-a30a-c414fafa2803&comment=сяма&serviceId=157&fields=blablablafieds

I have logged sent Request Parameters. And on my logs i see that russian characters is not posting correctly. For example i have posted **Сяма** but in my logs i have found **Ñ?Ñ?Ð¼Ð°**

I have added filters to web.xml file:

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

But it did not help me

What can you advise to me?

Answer (score 0):

Dont you need to URL encode these parameters in your test request? Else they will break when decoded in your request parameter mapping step, just like you described

Comment: actually you only need to encode unicode and special chars .. thats the whole point of URL encoding of get parameters

Comment: i have encoded it with http://www.codenet.ru/services/urlencode-urldecode/    . and then post encoded commend i result same

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if my answer will be helpful for other servlet containers but on Tomcat you need also specify `URIEncoding` attribute of each `Connector` element within `conf/server.xml`.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" OTHER_ATTRIBUTES />

<Connector SSLEnabled="true" port="8443" scheme="https" secure="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8" OTHER_ATTRIBUTES />
```

For more information look at [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)